# Upgrade straight to 16 / 32 GB Ram on DDR3 , 1 Ram slot

Tags: memory, upgrade

My computer is 8GB DDR3 Hp laptop 250 G2.
Intel Pentium N3510 @1.99 GHz

I upgraded from 4GB RAM to 8GB
now i have a question i want to be sure of as i currently use one slot for RAM , Can i just get a 16GB RAM and upgrade once and for all as my computer is DDR3.

Please let me know.

Comment: it will depend on the motherboard's capabilities. Please give us the make and model number of the computer or its motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum RAM addressable by that processor is 8GB, so adding more in any configuration will not help.

See [Intel® Pentium® Processor N3510](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/76751/intel-pentium-processor-n3510-2m-cache-2-00-ghz.html)

Ideally, to achieve correct interleaving, that should be done using two identical 4GB cards.